# uisearch bar width is reduced when change orientation from landscape to portrait

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, uisearchbar

I am using tableview with search bar display controller, it shows good in portait and landscape view, but rotate from landscape to portrait search bar size is reduced, how to change the original size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first your should catch the orientation:

```
 //AppDelegate.h
 @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
 @property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) NSInteger isPortrait;

//AppDelegate.m
@synthesize isPortrait;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

   isPortrait = 1;

}
```

Implementation state:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceRotated:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

 //methode deviceRotated 

-(void)deviceRotated:(NSNotification*)notification{

   AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
   if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
   {
      [self searchBarLandscape];
       app.isPortrait = NO;
  }
  else{
     [self searchBarPortrait];
     app.isPortrait = YES;
  }

}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return YES;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    AppDelegate * app = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) 
   {
    app.isPortrait = 1;
   }
  else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
  {
    app.isPortrait = 0;
  }
  [self prepareSearchBarOrientation];

}


-(void)prepareSearchBarOrientation
{

   AppDelegate * app = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   if (app.isPortrait)
   {
       [self searchBarPortrait];//Set Frame here
   }
  else
  {
      [self searchBarLandscape];

  }

}
```

Comment: Please show me the image of issue when rotate from landscape to portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the searchBar's frame in the rotation delegate methods or Try auto resizing in XIB.

See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5) for a better idea.

Comment: initially portait mode frame is correct after rotating to landscape mode show correct width after that and back to portait width is reduced