# Orientation change issue in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

My application is working fine for iOS5. But for iOS6 I am getting the following orientation problem.

I have a ViewController VC1. when you rotate (change the orientation to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) I want to present another ViewController VC2 and when you rotate back I need to dismiss VC2 and the VC1 should be in Portrait mode.

I am using tabBar in my application and I want this feature only for the first tab.

In tabBar I have written

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.selectedViewController;
    if ([nav.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MainViewController class]])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
} 
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    //Here I am writing code for presenting view(using notifications)
    // but When I rotate the device to landscape it's getting called but when I rotate back 
    //to portrait I not getting called.
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: which method that u use to implement orientation ?

Comment: I have edited(explained) my question.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6

Answer (score 0):

Please try this with ios 6 :(Example)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

}
```

Comment: Do I need to write in tabBar or viewController?

Comment: Where do I need to present the viewController?

Comment: Try:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330515/uisearch-bar-width-is-reduced-when-change-orientation-from-landscape-to-portait/16331497?noredirect=1#comment23390678_16331497

Comment: That question is not at all related to this.